# How can I make the edges of a rectangle diamond shape?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, rectangles

Here is an [image](http://images.ipad.qualityindex.com/product_screenshots/446477/ipad/mzl.hbkgljgs.1024x1024-65.jpg) for reference. 
What I was able to do so far is make the edges in the rectangle round and now I want the edges to be diamond shape or somewhat close to the image.

Code

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="test.FXMLDocumentController">
    <Button prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200">
        <shape>
            <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" width="200" height="30"/>
        </shape>
    </Button>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: What is the rectangle you refer to in your image - the quadrilateral ([rhombus](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Quadrilaterals.svg/2000px-Quadrilaterals.svg.png)) next to the letter "A"?  Rather than linking to an offsite resource, you can embed images in your question if you have enough reputation.

Comment: @jewelsea There all the same so it could be either the one next to the letter A, B, C or D.

Comment: I'm a little confused why you set the shape of a button.  What is the button from your screenshot (is it the rhombus next to the letter "A"), or is it the entire answer area "A: Water", including the blue area around it?  I am unsure whether you are really asking how to make a button shaped like a Rhombus or how to make a button shaped like the long flat shape with tapered sides like you have in your image.

Comment: At the moment I'm only concern with the shape. Not the contents inside the shape.

Comment: @jewelsea "how to make a button shaped like the long flat shape with tapered sides like you have in your image". This is what I'm asking

Comment: @jewelsea specifically with the tampered sides.

Comment: @jewelsea my example shows a rounded rectangle. What I want is to recreate that rectangle with those tampered sides.

Comment: Use an [SVGPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/SVGPath.html) to define your button shape.  Please try to make your questions clearer so that it is not necessary to ask a many questions to work our what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just crop that image and add it as a graphic to some JavaFX control, for instance to the button.

Answer (score -1):

This example shows as to make diamond-shaped button.
Try this:

```
 <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


    <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="351.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
       <children>
          <Button layoutX="125.0" layoutY="104.0" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="78.0" style="-fx-rotate: 45; -fx-background-color: #00ff00;" />
       </children>
    </Pane>
```

Comment: Do not simply paste in code and say "Try this." You need to include an explanation of what your code is doing. Pasting in blocks of code defeats the purpose of SO which is, essentially, to **teach** people how to code and to create a database of answers to common and more technical coding questions. By simply dropping in blocks of code, an OP does not learn how to code, they learn how to copy and paste other people's code and will never learn **WHY** their code works. Do not do this in future. Fix your answer to include an explanation please.

Comment: Sorry. I added a description